# Как сравнить два пароля не прибегая к JavaScript?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, html5, form, input, сопоставление-с-образцом

Есть нечто такое:

```css
main .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- head -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- head end -->
<main>
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="text" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Name" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Password (again)" type="password" required />
                <!--pattern ???-->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Register</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</main>
```

Вопрос в том, есть ли такая возможность, обратиться к полю password из поля confirmation по pattern (или любым иным способом), чтобы сравнить эти два поля не прибегая к функции на JS?

Comment: До сих пор такого не сделано http://stackoverflow.com/q/9142527/5441700 видимо.

Comment: @Visman, ясно, печально. В любом случае, благодарю за ссылку. :3